# NetSuite Suitelet not picking up Shopify Webhook

Tags: javascript, shopify, netsuite, webhooks, suitescript2.0

**What Is Happening**

My Webhook from shopify is not passing the details to my SuiteScript 2.0 Suitelet in NetSuite.

**What do I want to happen**

I want shopify to send the JSON object to my netsuite Suitelet so I can process the order in NetSuite.

**Details**

I am trying to make a connection between shopify and Netsuite using Shopify's webhooks.

I have set up a webhook as follows
[image]

The URL for my webhook is;

```
https://XXXXXXX-sb1.extforms.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/scriptlet.nl?script=XXX&deploy=XX&compid=XXXXXXX_SB1&h=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&caller=ecommerce&key=XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX
```

This link calls a Suitelet which when I personally paste the link in the URL is works. However when I click "Send Test Notification" I do not see any evidencethat the Suitelet has executed. The first line of the suitelet is;

```
log.debug("Running");
```

I have changed the Webhooks URL to instead go to RequestBin and sure enough the webhook works.

**WHAT HAVE I TRED**

1. I have removed the extra query string parameters "caller" and "key"
   from the URL. Does not solve the problem.
2. I have confirmed the Webhook works when changing the URL to RequestBin.

Answer (score 1):

One frustrating limitation with public Suitelets is that they require the `User-Agent` header to claim to be a browser. (See for example [SuiteAnswer #38695](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/38695/kw/user%20agent%20suitelet)).

I had the same issue as you with a BigCommerce webhook, and what I ended up doing was proxy the webhook through a simple Google Cloud Function that modified the user agent.

```
const request = require('request');

exports.webhook = (req, res) => {
  request.post(
    {
      url: process.env.NETSUITE_SUITELET_URL,
      body: req.body,
      json: true,
      headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5',
        Authorization: req.headers['authorization'],
      },
    },
    function(error, response, body) {
      res.send(body);
    }
  );
};
```